# Where is the Node console?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, typescript

I have a project created in Visual Studio 2017 using the `TypeScript Basic Node.js Express 4 Application` template.

I can't find the Node console unlike the `cmd` window with a NTVS project. As a result I can't locate the output for (server) `console.log()`.

If there is an exception before the web server is fired up, VS just exit unceremoniously without any warning or messages.

Where is the Node console window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried replicating your problem. I bootstrapped the project using the template you specified and in the app.ts file added this:

```
import express = require('express');
import path = require('path');

import routes from './routes/index';
import users from './routes/user';

if (new Date().getFullYear() == 2017)
    throw Error("OOPS");

var app = express();
// the rest is the default
```

When build and run the app results in this:
[image: screenshot]
So the window stays open and you can read about the error.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for this window which I had in my old Node.js project in Visual Studio.  This window is completely missing in my VS now. I have not rebooted in 30 days. Perhaps something is corrupted in my VS,

Comment: Rebooted, and the console can now be seen!

Comment: I'm glad you resolved it, you should post the reboot as an answer and accept it :)